# How to add autofocus for ng-select which is there inside bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-modal

I am using ng-select inside modal. I want to add autofocus for ng-select, I can able to add focus for input field which is there inside modal but if I try same thing for ng-select it is not working. Please let me know how we can add focus for ng select.

Comment: please show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by this way

```
this.ngSelectInput.filterInput.nativeElement.focus();
```